# I can't set the text in my Browser control to what I need

Tags: c#, dom, webbrowser-control, domdocument

```
            System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document = this.webBrowser1.Document;
            HtmlElementCollection hec = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement el in hec)
            {
                if (el.GetAttribute("name").Equals("_MYPW"))
                {
                    var form = this.webBrowser1.Document.Forms[0]; //form element 
                    var input = form.Children[0]; //input element 
                    input.SetAttribute("_MYPW", "type some text"); //set the input value 
                }
            }
```

I want to set the text for the

```
<input name="_MYPW" type=password>
```

How can I do this? The above code doesn't work properly. It doesn't input any text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (el.GetAttribute("name").Equals("_MYPW"))
{                        
    el.SetAttribute("value", "some text");
    clickNextButton(hec);
}
```

This types the text

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the `_MYPW` attribute.

You probably want to set the `value` attribute.

Comment: Please elaborate because I don't know what you mean by i want to set the value attribute. I thought I was setting the value to the tag with name "_MYPW"

Comment: Do you want to change the name of the element? No, you want to change its content